# Firefox crashes on Ubuntu with xfce

Tags: firefox, xfce

I have set up a fresh copy of Ubuntu 16.10 on an old PC. I can run Firefox (v52.0) on the computer as long as I am logged into it directly, but Firefox crashes every time if I try to launch it in an RDP window.
I have looked at the crash report, but there is nothing illuminating in there.
I am accessing the Ubuntu machine remotely from Windows 10, via RDP. I have installed XFCE4 on Ubuntu and I am using Remote Desktop (mstsc) from Windows 10 to connect to the Ubuntu machine. The connection works, I can open programs inside my remote desktop session, and I can use the Browser Ubuntu app (a web browser). I just cannot use Firefox.
I have un/re/installed Firefox, and I have tried running it in Safe Mode - same crashes.

Did anyone encounter this / know how to fix it?

I can provide more details about my configuration (not sure what is relevant).

```
$ firefox -safe-mode
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 3437
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Failed to open curl lib from binary, use libcurl.so instead
```

Comment: Somewhat related: I have set up *two* old PCs (different hardware) with the same version of Ubuntu (16.10), installed the latest patches and drivers, etc, the latest Firefox (52.0) - and the crashes happen the same way on both machines. I have installed Chrome on both machines, and Chrome works.

Comment: As suggested by someone else: Firefox works if it is launched as `sudo firefox`. It prints this message, and then it runs fine: `(firefox:16182): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/MyUser/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
ERROR - ContextualIdentityService - Unknown version found in /home/MyUser/.mozilla/firefox/n7ikuxsh.default/containers.json`

Comment: I have the same problem in 16.04 LTS when running Firefox in Mate over XRDP remote session. Running Firefox with pure X Window protocol over ssh session works but is too slow to work in Internet :( I haven't found good solution yet :( It was working fine before, just got broken recently with some update...

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem on 16.10 with Mate over XRDP. I initially fixed it by installing Firefox 51 like so:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove firefox
$ wget https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/11952503/+files/firefox_51.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.10.2_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i firefox_51.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.10.2_amd64.deb
$ sudo apt-mark hold firefox
```

However I found the bug that is actually tracking this problem, here:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1345413

I was able to confirm that by setting the LOGNAME environment variable, the problem goes away:

```
$ export LOGNAME=$USER
$ firefox &
```

The bug is quite old (October 2016), but it appears recently to have been fixed upstream. The 52.0.1 release of Firefox on Ubuntu 16.10 does not contain the fix yet however, so for now manually setting LOGNAME is the way to get around the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for providing here the workaround, this works with Lubuntu 16.04.2 through xRDP.

Comment: YES! that was it. Ubuntu 14 server LXDE xrdp from Win7. I added that to the end of  `/home/username/.profile`  and worked on reboot.

Comment: Today (March 30) I received the update to Firefox 52.0.2. I can confirm that the workaround with the LOGNAME environment variable, is no longer necessary.

Comment: Hmm, does not work for me with Thunderbird 52.2.1.

Comment: What did work:sudo apt purge --auto-remove thunderbird and then reinstalling via sudo apt install thunderbird.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation though I'm running Ubuntu 16.10 with XFCE in lxd container, and logging in with xrdp. I did not try to run it on bare-metal/virt and assumed it was not working because of containerisation. Seems the problem is somewhere else. The workaround I have found is to run with sudo: it works as a workaround.  Downgrading works too.

I also did try to run binary builds provided by Mozilla, and there is the same error: won't run with regular user, but works with sudo. I tried stable, beta, developer and nightly (52, 53, 54, 55) - they all give the same error...

Comment: same here, I have the same problem as well. Please fix it asap.